# Place a layout between other two but only in a portion of the screen width

Tags: android, layout, graphics

I want to achieve this result:

[image: final view]

Inside the middle layout I want place 2 textview.
I guess that I must to use a FrameLayout or a RelativeLayout to place the middle view in that position.

Another problem is I need that the text at the left of the middle layout(TEXT 1 and 2), doesn't go underneath it.

Thanks

Comment: Show some code that shows what you tried.

Comment: I've not tryied anything because I don't know how to place that layout in the middle. I need only a hint not a working code.

Comment: You can specify negative margins to achieve what you trying to do.

Comment: I has to fit the 2 textviews(1 line each). But I'm able to customize the margins. The problem is only how place a view in that position. However I prefer weights instead of a fixed dp value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">




    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#aa0000"
            >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView121"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>



    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00aa00"

        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this..

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:background="#FFFF0000"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:background="#FF0000FF"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFFF00FF"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FF00FFFF"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="153dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:background="#FFF0F0FF"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FF0FFF0F"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just that the top margin alone you can set in code/xml!

Comment: The middle layout is not in the middle like in my image.

Comment: You have to calculate 30% of height in runtime and set as top margin.  It is like: 30% of screen height - half of middle layout's height = top margin of middle layout.